# Change view's content of previous window in titanium

Tags: android, windows, view, titanium

I have a situation here. I have a view with a label. And I have a button. Once it is clicked, it will open a new window with a textbox and close button. And once I have inserted a text and press the close button, the window will close and the label at the previous window will automatically updated with the word that I insert into the textbox. May I know how can I update the view of the previous window? Thank you.

Titanium 1.6.1, Android 1.6

Comment: the 'new window with a textbox and a close button' Is that a dialog? or a separate activity?

Answer (score 0):

you would pass the value back through firing an event OR you could pass the label object from the first screen to the second screen.